# Drupal views, how does views get data from this query? (sql, might not be Drupal specific)

Tags: sql, drupal-7, drupal-views

I used Drupal views to generate the query below.  It gets all users of group x.

```
SELECT users.name AS users_name, users.uid AS uid,'user' AS field_data_field_blogging_name_user_entity_type
FROM 
{users} users
INNER JOIN {users_roles} users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid
WHERE (( (users.status <> '0') AND (users_roles.rid = '5') ))
```

The problem is I also want some information that is in another table. In a table called 'field_data_field_blogging_name' I want to get the 'field_blogging_name_value' which is identified by entity_id (ie entity_id == uid).

When I run this query, I get a simple 'user' placeholder.  My question is why does views use these placeholders and is it possible to write the above query so it works?  If so how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be able to add the relationship in the views UI, under the Advanced Settings
2. If for some reason you want to do it in code, in HOOK_views_query_alter you will need to add the join using something like

   $query->leftjoin('field_data_field_blogging_name', 'blogname', 'node.nid = blogname.entity_id');
    $query->fields('blogname', array('field_blogging_name_value',));